# Using macros to parse string to expression C++

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program that takes input as a string and then passes that string to a macro which is supposed to insert the string as a plain-text expression but the macro is not behaving as I would suspect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

#define  PARSE(a) a;


using namespace std;

int main() {
    string c ;
    int b;
    cin >> c;

    b = PARSE(c);

    cout << b;

    return 0;
}
```

This code will not compile, it gives an error saying that I cannot convert string to int, however PARSE(c) should not be treated like a string it should just be replaced by plain text.

Comment: The preprocessor runs even before the regular compiler does (hence the name preprocessor). It can't use runtime values. What you want is a plain old function to convert a string to int, which has plenty of existing presence on this site.

Comment: I suppose `#define PARSE(a) atoi(a);` (with a `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top) would be considered cheating?

Comment: Ok, I see. The preprocessor would just replace PARSE(c) with the plain-text c.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to parse string to expression?

Comment: Are you talking about a Python `eval`/`exec`/`compile` equivalent in C++?

Comment: One rule in C++ is that one should **avoid macros** as much as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you are really trying to convert std::string (c) to int and it can't be done (b). 
If you want to access the plain text, once you are using std::string, you should call the c_str() method, example:

```
cout << c.c_str();
```

@edit:
If you are trying to do something like "eval()" from PHP, you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11078610/12385171

Comment: I am not talking about plain-text in that sense, I wanted the pre-compiler to directly change the text in the uncompiled c++ file.

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide, I added a reference, tell me if it is what you want.