# How can I convert string to code at run time

Tags: c++, string, runtime

I am generating strings containing `if else` expressions. I was wondering if I can execute this expressions at run time? Here's an example:

```
string s = "if(x > 10) {Fly = true;} else {Fly = False;}";
Execute (s);
```

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Not unless you apply [Greenspun's 10th rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule).

Comment: What about https://root.cern.ch/cling ?   Or have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use TCC ( http://bellard.org/tcc/ ). It allows to compile and run code natively at runtime. Another approach is to use an interpreter, there are plenty out there (LUA, Python etc, see list [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)).

Comment: Ohh sounds interesting, yes if course it would be better. I actually Know pythong and i started to think how complicated it is.

Comment: And One question Rax please. I can include it in my code right?
Like for example in the for **Loop** I can use an **expression** to compile the string

Comment: Yes, you can compile any c code this includes expressions and any c language feature. For your needs you could make a c functions that takes arguments and calculates the return the evaluated expression. TCC will compile that code and you can get a pointer to that function and evaluate it any time you want. I think all the code in TCC is bound by a context so as long as the context is initialized the compiled code can be executed.

Comment: However i do not encourage you to use it on a production project since i don't know if was used on a mass scale and it could have it's problems (memory leaks , crashes , etc). For a production project you should use a scripting language like LUA , you can even run PYTHON code if you want , check http://ironpython.net/

Comment: Or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html if you don't want managed code.

Answer (score 4):

One does not simply interpret C/C++ code... AFAIK you just can't.
(except if you compile another binary and run it from cmd line maybe...)

Note: You can write

```
fly = (x > 10);
```

instead of

```
if(x > 10){
    fly = true;
}else{
    fly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. C++ is a compiled language and has no eval-function or the-like. You may want to include a scripting engine into your program, like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/)

Comment: Yes I saw that on Java they have an Eval-function, thought that it will be the same here.

Comment: Even in Java they don't (because Java is also a somewhat compiled language). In JavaScript however they do. Don't confuse Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

int n;
cin >> n;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << string((n - 1) - i, ' ') << string(2 * i + 1, '*') << endl;
    }

    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << string((n - 1) - i, ' ') << string(2 * i + 1, '*') << endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

Comment: Question not understood. How does this turn a string into executable code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).