# Which languages will call C++ with no explicit bridging?

Tags: c++

While developing a new product, we decided to go for a mix of C++ and C#, haven been told that bridging them to allow the C# code to call the C++ code would be easy (spoiler, it's not).

We're pretty experienced C++ programmers and not at all C# programmers so we pretty much just had to believe what we've read. A few attempts to call C and Objective-C was promising and we even found a few articles that showed how to make an unmanaged C++ class available in C# -- or at least we thought. The C++ code in the articles, wasn't C++, but instead the horrible monster C++/CLI that Microsoft seems to think is C++. Since we're doing the C# stuff to get some bits "for free" in macOS and Windows, C++/CLI isn't an option either :-(.

Anyway, plenty of people have claimed that it's easy to call C++ code from some specific programming language, but so far, I haven't seen a single one that will allow me to do so (I haven't been paying too much attention to this, so please provide me with an obvious example). C++ invariably always means C with no C++ stuff at all; no namespaces, classes, no stl, lambdas or anything. Just plain dumb C.

So, are there *any* languages, besides C++(/CLI) that *will* allow me to do the following:

1. Create an instance of a class, using a C++ constructor, and dispatch it with a C++ destructor.
2. Call member functions on an object ( `foo f; f.foo();`) with a C++ class.
3. Use `std::vector`, `std::find_if`, `std::string` and other stuff from the stl. Complete coverage of the stl is not required.
4. Use overloaded functions (i.e. `f()`, `f(int)`, `f(std::string)`)
5. Use overloaded operators (`foo operator + (foo, foo)`)
6. Use C++11, C++14 and/or C++17 features.
7. Use RAII (rather important IMHO).
8. Use namespaces.

Comment: Hm, define "easy". You can pass anything from and to Python for example, stuff like swig or boost.python helps with that. If that counts as "easy" I don't know.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I gather OP is after the opposite (calling C++ from Python, for example).

Comment: @Quentin Works either way, with swig at least.

Comment: Different implementations of C++ **can't** call code generated by each other, in general

Comment: i guess you have one of 2 options here: 1) rewrite your program in the target language; 2) call c-bound functions from the target language and move around simple values and pointers returned from them. Though some languages, like Java would require an additional layer between the languages.

Comment: If you want to develop plugins to PHP, Java, Oracle, Python, Whatever then settle for C and it will work. With C++, it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What languages will call C++ with no explicit bridging?

The short answer to this question is: **NONE**

Remember that a programming language is a *specification* written in some technical report, usually in English. For examples, read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the spec of C11) or [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) (the spec of Scheme). For C++, see [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Actually, you are interested in *implementations*, e.g. in compilers and interpreters for your programming languages. These implementations are practically software. And then the answer might become: *it depends* (notably on the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) used & targetted by your compiler and system).

See for examples this [list of ABIs](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) for Linux.

> plenty of people have claimed that it's easy to call C++ code from some specific programming language,

The C [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) are quite common, and it might help to declare every C++ function callable from outside as `extern "C"`. But there is [**no silver bullet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), and details matter a lot.

> So, are there any languages, besides C++(/CLI) that will allow me to do the following:

*list of C++ features skipped*

Probably not.

You probably need at least to understand more about [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) approaches. I recommend understanding more about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), e.g. by reading the [*GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/) (at least for underlying concepts & terminology). Learn more about [foreign function interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) (in some cases, the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) might help) and [language bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding).

You might also consider *generating* some of the C++ or C glue code, maybe with [SWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) (or write your own C++ glue code generator).

On [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) providing [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) capable of loading [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) at runtime (e.g. Linux with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)/[dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html); but other OSes often have similar facilities) you could even consider generating some C or C++ glue code at *runtime* in some temporary file, compile it as a temporary plugin, and dynamically loading that plugin. You could also consider [JIT-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) (or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/)).

I recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), and probably [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces). Of course, learn something about OSes, e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Reading about [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linker/) could also help.

As an excellent example of cleverly gluing C++, look into [CLASP](https://github.com/drmeister/clasp) and see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8X69_42Mj-g).

But whatever approach you take, you'll need *a lot of work* (years, not weeks).

Answer (score 8):

No. There is no such language.

Unless you count Objective-C++. But that falls pretty much in the same bucket as C++/CLI, in being C++ with some extensions. And C++/CX is another such beast.

There are some interop tools that can work with C++ classes (SWIG for example), but I have never heard of a tool that is capable of instantiating C++ templates (like vector or find_if) on demand.

Answer (score 2):

C++ as a language does not have a defined ABI (Application Binary Interface) - which basically means that there is no universal standard of what a C++ class/function call/template would look like in binary form on any given platform, or across platforms.

What that means is that there is no universal way to call C++ code from other languages, on different platforms, or even across compilers on the same platform.  It also means that the people who are telling you "it's easy to call C++ code from XYZ language"  are mostly incorrect (or at least incredibly incomplete).

Where there are interfaces it's either because the provider of the interface controls the ABI (C++/CLI with .NET), or because there is a translation layer from C++ to something like the C calling convention (Boost::python).

Some work has been done towards attempting to define an ABI per-platform (http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4028.pdf), but as far as I'm aware it has not yet been accepted into C++17.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into using C++ interpreter, which allows for the fine-grained control you ask for. But I don't know of any that "just works", see also:
[Have you used any of the C++ interpreters (not compilers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers)

Answer (score 0):

D programming language is very **close**: https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html