# Why was C++ mentioned as a 'usually' compiled language?

Tags: c++

In the [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info), it is stated that

> C++ is a ... (usually) compiled ... programming language ...

Yet [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/info/description/) assert that C++ is a compiled language without mentioning any exceptions.

Could you please tell us the reason why C++ is **usually**, yet not **always**, a compiled language? When can C++ be deemed a non-compiled language?

---

Wikipedia:

> C++ is a compiled language, with implementations of it available on many platforms.

cplusplus.com:

> ... is a compiled language. 
>   C++ compiles directly to a machine's native code, allowing

This may suggest that there are non-compiled forms of C++. What makes the wiki to state 'usually'?

Comment: I think there has been some *interpreter* of some *subset* of C++. Look into [Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) and [Cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling)

Comment: eg the ROOT framework has a [c++ interpreter](https://root.cern.ch/cint)

Comment: I'm guessing the prevalence of LLVM and clang.  Though that's a compiler too.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69539/6525260. Here is [one interpreter called Cling](https://github.com/vgvassilev/cling).

Comment: Note: cplusplus.com is generally a poor reference site full of errors. Prefer cppreference.com

Comment: At last,**the difference between a compiler and an interpreter is very blurry.** [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) looks and smells like an interpreter, but it actually compiles to machine code *every* [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) interaction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because "C++" as defined by the C++ Standard is only a programming language, operating in an abstract machine. Implementations are free to do whatever they want to emulate the behaviour of that abstract machine.

Therefore, regardless of whether someone actually makes a C++ interpreter, saying that C++ is always compiled would be an unfounded assumption.

Answer (score 7):

There is no technical reason why you can't write a *C++ interpreter* rather than a compiler and I believe some have been written in the past.

C is also a (usually) compiled language, but I myself wrote a (slow, recursive decent) C89 interpreter some 20 years ago. C++ is just a (*much*) harder version of the same problem.

Comment: Indeed, there was even a commercial product beginning of the ninetees, called Rational Instant C.

Answer (score 2):

There are some interpreters for subsets of C++ ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers)), but the overwhelming majority of C++ work is done using compilers.  Using interpreters is so rare that no C++ literature or sizeable C++ library or program not explicitly about/for those interpreters will restrict itself to the subset of C++ that can be used on an interpreter.

With C++, it's actually more common to compile further C++ on the fly than interpret any.

For whatever it's worth, the most recent related news I've read (on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/)) was about a [C++17 REPL](https://github.com/inspector-repl/inspector).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases C++ is compiled but, e.g., [cling](https://github.com/root-project/cling) is a C++ interpreter. I haven't tried it much but it seems to be a fairly complete C++ implementation.