# C++ parsing expressions, breaking down the order of evaluation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an expression parser. One part I'm stuck on is breaking down an expression into blocks via its appropriate order of precedence.

I found the order of precedence for C++ operators [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). But where exactly do I split the expression based on this?

I have to assume the worst of the user. Here's a really messy over-exaggerated test example:

```
if (test(s[4]) < 4 && b + 3 < r && a!=b && ((c | e) == (g | e)) ||
   r % 7 < 4 * givemeanobj(a & c & e, b, hello(c)).method())
```

Perhaps it doesn't even evaluate, and if it doesn't I still need to break it down to determine that.

It should break down into blocks of singles and pairs connected by operators. Essentially it breaks down into a tree-structure where the branches are the groupings, and each node has two branches.

Following the order of precedence the first thing to do would be to evaluate the `givemeanobj()`, however that's an easy one to see. The next would be the multiplication sign. Does that split everything before the `*` into a separate , or just the `4`? `4 * givemeanobj` comes before the `<`, right? So that's the first grouping?

Is there a straightforward rule to follow for this?

Comment: Are you trying to write a C++ interpreter? Many exist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers

Comment: *"first thing to do would be to evaluate the `givemeanobj()`, however that's an easy one to see"* Is it? You need to evaluate `test(s[4])` first, because the lhs of `&&` has to be evaluated before the rhs.

Comment: You also need to account for (1) associativity of operators (2) logical operators (`&&` and `||`) do short-circuiting (3) in function calls - the commas are not the comma operator (4) some numeric operators (e.g. `%`) and bitwise operators (`&`, `|`) are only applicable to integral types.    [I'm assuming none of the variables in your "test example" are instances of classes with overloaded operators].

Comment: A [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) may be what you are looking for. The "analysis" (dissecting) of a complex expression is handled by the recursion.

Comment: Also, as noted on the page you are linking, "_Precedence and associativity are compile-time concepts and are independent from [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), which is a runtime concept._"

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a straightforward rule to follow for this?

Yes, use a parser generator such as [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/).  You write your language specification formally, and it will generate code which parses all valid expressions (and no invalid ones).  ANTLR is nice in that it can give you an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) which you can easily traverse and evaluate.

Or, if the language you are parsing is actually C++, use Clang, which is a proper compiler and happens to be usable as a library as well.